# What happened to Job's family?

Tags: job

Why did God kill jobs family? What did they ever done wrong? What happened to them after God made a bet with the devil?

Comment: what? why the downvotes?

Comment: The creator has the right to create and destroy whatever he wants.

Comment: i think its the description: you say God killed Jobs family and God made a bet, but if God is all-knowing what is a bet? In essence, living is a grace we humans get from God, he has all right to take it away, though he didn't take it away but the devil did. God does not want us to die, our sins makes us mortal, not God wanting to kill us.

Comment: What happend to de family we don't know, the bible does not say anything about that. I think its safe to assume that it depended on their believe, like it does for everybody.

Comment: Well this was closed because it is a Truth question, but the simplest answer is that the story of Job is poetry and not history. Just like Song of Solomon. The very nature of the story and the writing style clearly show that it is poetical in nature, meant to show that the righteous praise God always, through every storm, through darkness and light; they worship Him unwaveringly. The idea that the story is factual is not only dubious and neglectful of the above, but it is quite uncommon among scholars.

Comment: @fredsbend This question certainly has issues, but it isn't exactly your classic truth question. And I'm sorry but your "answer" in a comment here would get pretty fast down vote from me. The writing style doesn't _clearly_ show anything. The language and writing style is so old and hard we can't even be sure we know what linguistic style it is, and the belief that is is historical is _not_ uncommon among scholars. Except maybe non Christian scholars, but that's hardly the inference in the context of this site.

Comment: @Caleb I guess we disagree, then. The first paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Job) spells out what I am referring to by calling it a poem (though I concede that does not necessarily mean that it is not also historical). It seems quite apparent to me. As for it being uncommon among scholars I hear very few calling it historical, save maybe that a guy named Job did live and suffer, then lived well afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Job was a man who loved God. Satan told God that he only reason Job loved Him was because He allowed him to be wealthy. So to prove him wrong, God allowed Satan to take all of Job's possessions. Job's oldest son's home was destroyed by a violent wind. All of Job's children were partying there and were killed. In his sadness, Job tore his robe. Despite all his loses he still loved God!  Since Satan's 'theory' didn't turn out well, he proposed that Job would turn away from God if He made him very ill. Again, God allowed Job to become sick but he still did not turn away from God! Even his own wife told Job to curse The Lord, but he still remained faithful. Soon, Job had 10 more children and had twice as much riches as he had before.

Comment: so what happened to the original family? they just got killed because god had a bet with satan? just to prove satan wrong? he killed people?

Comment: It wasn't really a "bet" but rather a test. Job's suffering over his family led him to grow spiritually.

Comment: @FFCoder They were killed but Job did received more family members and possibly God Almighty did  send  same souls of family members who were killed in these new family members. We would never know God's capacity nor decipher His works.